# pthread имя потока

Tags: многопоточность, pthread

Как задать имя потока, что бы в отладчике был виден не id потока, а его имя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[prctl](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/prctl.2.html)  с `PR_SET_NAME`.

В glibc v2.12 есть `pthread_setname_np` и `pthread_getname_np`:

```
#include <pthread.h>  // or maybe <pthread_np.h> for some OSes

// Linux
int pthread_setname_np(pthread_t thread, const char *name);

// NetBSD: name + arg work like printf(name, arg)
int pthread_setname_np(pthread_t thread, const char *name, void *arg);

// FreeBSD & OpenBSD: function name is slightly different, and has no return value
void pthread_set_name_np(pthread_t tid, const char *name);

// Mac OS X: must be set from within the thread (can't specify thread ID)
int pthread_setname_np(const char*);
```